# Android GPS requestLocationUpdates weird behavior

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-workmanager

I'm trying to update my application from using Job Scheduler to using Work Manager. I have started calling my GPS class from both a service and worker class. The old version works perfectly, the new worker class returns 0.0 for lat and long.

```
Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: 4.1");
Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: locationManger = " + locationManager);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
Log.d("Network", "Network");
Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: 4.2");
```

The above is in the GPS class. In the service the debug log prints:

```
D/GPSTracker: getLocation: 4.1
D/GPSTracker: getLocation: locationManger = android.location.LocationManager@9438dd2
D/Network: Network D/GPSTracker: getLocation: 4.2
```

But in the worker class it prints:

```
Log.d(TAG, "getLocation: 4.1");
```

And then breaks out of the loop. No crash, no error, it just hits the

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()
```

line of code, and exits, and for the life of my I cannot work out why it would do this in one class and not in another.

Anyone have any ideas?

Adding the worker request code:

```
mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this);
PeriodicWorkRequest mRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(LocationManager.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);
```

The thing is, the worker runs on squedule just fine, the problem is with the line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

For some reason, it hits that line, and just exits, it never reaches the logd code in the next line. It's like the worker cannot request location updates for some reason, and does not throw an exception. I don't think its context related, as I have tried using Application context which does the same thing.

Comment: See any waning arise in your **logcate**.

Comment: No warnings, no nothing. It just exits @TariqulIslam

Comment: Con you post your Worker code and how you enqueue it?

Comment: added, thanks @pfmaggi

Comment: If you're using a Worker (you just pasted a line of the worker, so I'm just guessing), it only supports synchronous code.
Take a look at last year ADS talk on WorkManager, it covers this a bit: https://youtu.be/83a4rYXsDs0?t=730